# MVC 3/C# Can't use variables that have been declared inside if statements

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I'm trying to write code in my controller that when run, will create a bunch of variables and then send an email using a template that has placeholders to include the variables. However it's assigning information from a user account to the variables and if the user hasn't filled in that information yet it will crash. As a work around I declared them inside if statements that checked to make sure they weren't null first. But now when I try to pass them to the email template it tells me the variable doesn't exist. If I remove the if statement it works again. Any ideas why?

Code is below...

```
if (UserContext != null && UserContext.Account != null)
        {

            if (UserContext.UserName != null)
            { string UserName = string.Format(UserContext.UserName); }

            if (UserContext.EmailAddress != null)
            { string EmailAddress = string.Format(UserContext.EmailAddress); }

            if (UserContext.Account.PrimaryContactFirstName != null)
            { string FirstName = string.Format(UserContext.Account.PrimaryContactFirstName); }

            if (UserContext.Account.PrimaryContactLastName != null)
            { string LastName = string.Format(UserContext.Account.PrimaryContactLastName); }

            if (UserContext.Account.PrimaryContactPhoneNumber != null)
            { string PhoneNumber = string.Format(UserContext.Account.PrimaryContactPhoneNumber); }

            if (UserContext.Account.HeadquartersAddressLine1 != null)
            {
                string AddressLine1 = string.Format(UserContext.Account.HeadquartersAddressLine1);

                if (UserContext.Account.HeadquartersAddressLine2 != null)
                { string AddressLine2 = string.Format(UserContext.Account.HeadquartersAddressLine2); }
            }

            if (UserContext.Account.HeadquartersCity != null)
            { string City = string.Format(UserContext.Account.HeadquartersCity); }

            if (UserContext.Account.HeadquartersState != null)
            { string State = string.Format(UserContext.Account.HeadquartersState); }

            if (UserContext.Account.HeadquartersZip != null)
            { string ZipCode = string.Format(UserContext.Account.HeadquartersZip); }

            if (UserContext.Account.Name != null)
            { string Name = string.Format(UserContext.Account.Name); }

            string body = string.Format(Resources.ContactUsLoggedInEmailTemplate, model.FirstName, model.LastName, model.PhoneNumber, model.Email, model.ReasonForContact, model.Message, UserName, EmailAddress, FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber, AddressLine1, AddressLine2, City, State, ZipCode, Name);

            string subject = string.Format("Web Submit: {0}", model.ReasonForContact);

            EmailHelper.SendEmail("support@website.com", subject, body, true);

        }
        if (UserContext == null)
        {
            string body = string.Format(Resources.ContactUsEmailTemplate, model.FirstName, model.LastName, model.PhoneNumber, model.Email, model.ReasonForContact, model.Message);

            string subject = string.Format("Web Submit: {0}", model.ReasonForContact);

            EmailHelper.SendEmail("support@website.com", subject, body, true);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("ContactConfirmation");
```

Comment: This looks way more complex than it likely needs to be. What is the purpose of `string.Format` here?

Comment: To be honest, it more than likely is. My programming language in this area is horribly limited and I'm just getting it to work in any way I can. If you have any suggestions as to making it more efficient they would be appreciated.

Comment: All (well, most of) the if/assigns are semantically equivalent to just assigning the value. If the value is null then the variable will have the default value (null for strings). If the value is a string then `string.Format(s) =likely= s` (except the `string.Format` can throw exceptions and the escapes will be removed), so the operation did nothing useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each variable only exists for the lifetime of the block in which it is created.  You have them vanishing instantly as each `if` block ends.  The solution is to declare all of the variables first, then assign values as needed.

This is one of the common annoyances of `try`/`catch` blocks.  Anything that might be useful later needs to be declared before the `try`.  If a constructor might throw an exception then it should be inside the `try` block.

Comment: After reading your answer it barely took me five minutes to fix a bug I've been working on for hours! Thanks so much!

Comment: Glad I could help.  For data types other than `string` have a look at [Nullable<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0(v=vs.95).aspx).  The next step in confusion is realizing that C# `null` doesn't have  much to do with a database [DBNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Because you are declaring the variables IN the If statements, they disappear once the If statment completes. Declare the variables at the top (for example: `string body;`, BEFORE any of the if checks) and then you should be able to pass them into your email.

```
string UserName;
string EmailAddress;
string FirstName;
....
if (UserContext != null && UserContext.Account != null)
        {

            if (UserContext.UserName != null)
            { UserName = string.Format(UserContext.UserName); }

            if (UserContext.EmailAddress != null)
            { EmailAddress = string.Format(UserContext.EmailAddress); }

            if (UserContext.Account.PrimaryContactFirstName != null)
            { FirstName = string.Format(UserContext.Account.PrimaryContactFirstName); }

            if (UserContext.Account.PrimaryContactLastName != null)
            { LastName = string.Format(UserContext.Account.PrimaryContactLastName); }

            if (UserContext.Account.PrimaryContactPhoneNumber != null)
            { PhoneNumber = string.Format(UserContext.Account.PrimaryContactPhoneNumber); }

            if (UserContext.Account.HeadquartersAddressLine1 != null)
            {
                AddressLine1 = string.Format(UserContext.Account.HeadquartersAddressLine1);

                if (UserContext.Account.HeadquartersAddressLine2 != null)
                { AddressLine2 = string.Format(UserContext.Account.HeadquartersAddressLine2); }
            }

            if (UserContext.Account.HeadquartersCity != null)
            { City = string.Format(UserContext.Account.HeadquartersCity); }

            if (UserContext.Account.HeadquartersState != null)
            { State = string.Format(UserContext.Account.HeadquartersState); }

            if (UserContext.Account.HeadquartersZip != null)
            { ZipCode = string.Format(UserContext.Account.HeadquartersZip); }

            if (UserContext.Account.Name != null)
            { Name = string.Format(UserContext.Account.Name); }

            string body = string.Format(Resources.ContactUsLoggedInEmailTemplate, model.FirstName, model.LastName, model.PhoneNumber, model.Email, model.ReasonForContact, model.Message, UserName, EmailAddress, FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber, AddressLine1, AddressLine2, City, State, ZipCode, Name);

            string subject = string.Format("Web Submit: {0}", model.ReasonForContact);

            EmailHelper.SendEmail("support@website.com", subject, body, true);

        }
        if (UserContext == null)
        {
            body = string.Format(Resources.ContactUsEmailTemplate, model.FirstName, model.LastName, model.PhoneNumber, model.Email, model.ReasonForContact, model.Message);

            subject = string.Format("Web Submit: {0}", model.ReasonForContact);

            EmailHelper.SendEmail("support@website.com", subject, body, true);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("ContactConfirmation");
```